# how to get Cisco IOS public key for automatic scp connection

Tags: scp, cisco

I want to backup the running-config of all switches per SCP to a server.

Question 1: is this possible with kron? Is there a better way and why?

Question 2: how can I get the public key of the switch to auto-authentificate the user to the server?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Trivial googling bringa up e.g. [this](http://glennmatthys.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/ssh-with-key-authentication-on-cisco-ios-devices/).

Answer (score 0):

You can ssh to cisco IOS using public key. In Cisco device, using this command:

```
ip ssh key-chain
```

or

```
ip ssh pubkey-chain
```

depend on your IOS version.

You can simply creat a bash file, schedule it to run with cron.

**Updated**

Do you try generating ssh key from cisco device:

```
crypto key generate rsa
```

then copy public key generated to Linux server, and try to connect?

Comment: Thank you. But that's to auth to the cisco device, I need to auth from the device to a server

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 1:

Assuming you mean `cron`, yes it's possible, and without knowing more details about your environment it'll be impossible to guess whether there is a better way or not.

Answer to question 2:
Sounds like you want the SSH/scp client to automatically accept the host key of the remote end.

The most secure way to do it would be to use `scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new ...`, which will auto-accept host keys of previously-unseen remote hosts, but will stop and alert if it sees that a previously-known host key has been altered.

If you trust that the risk of man-in-the-middle attacks is low and want even more convenience (or if you have an old SSH implementation), you could use `scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ...` which will accept all new and changed remote host keys automatically.

The default is equivalent to `scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=ask ...`.